# Regex to find/replace content within an xml file

Tags: regex

I an struggling to produce regex that will find all content in a file that exists between two nodes:
`<path>(.*)</path>`

Once I have this content, I need to replace part of it:
If it matches "`resource/group`"
I want to replace that part with "`%`"

Additionally, the string could contain more text following the beginning of that path...
e.g. "`resource/group/more/path/here`"
In this case, I would want it to be replaced as such "`%/more/path/here`"

A few caveats..

1. If the path is incorrectly using "`\`" anywhere, I need to convert all those to "`/`".
2. If there is a trailing slash at all, I need it removed.

Some test lines I have located throughout the xml document:

```
<path>resource/group/door/something/test/</path>
<path>resource\group\door\</path>
<path>resource/group/door\</path>
<path>resource/group/door</path>
<path>resource/group/</path>
<path>resource\group\</path>
<path>resource/group</path>
<path>resource\group</path>
```

Any assistance on how to put together this regex would be wonderful!
Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Use an XML Parser, here is why: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/460557

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple caveats here indeed, the first that I noticed is that you are seraching between the `path` nodes... but if you use `<path>.*</path>`, this will collect in a greedy fashion, meaning you are targetting all the text **between the beginning of the first node and the end of the last**, which is not what we want! Let's keep our search between each individual node, so we need to change this to lazy execution, using the `?` modifier; `<path>.*?<\path>`

I'm most familiar with using regex in python, so I'll use that as the base for the pseudocode we figure this out... so, suppose we now have a collection of nodes as:

```
import re
doctext = open(<<path to your file>>,encoding="utf-8",errors="ignore").read()
nodes_pattern = re.compile(r"<path>.*?<\path>")
nodes_text = nodes_pattern.findall(doctext)
```

Now, within these nodes, it seems that the goals are:

1. Replace `resource/group`, with `%`
2. Account for any `\` and swap to `/`
3. Drop trailing slashes (`\` and `/` ?)

However I feel that this would be best done in reverse fashion, so we can clean our text first (solving (2) and (3) before fixing the paths). But before we get crazy modifying our text, we have to recall that we want to replace the originals with the fixed nodes and slip them back into the original text, so what I would do (entirely optional) is store the original nodes and their adjusted versions in a dictionary for now, so that the changes can be reviewed before swapped in the text. So, lets spawn a dictionary as:

```
replacement_record = {original:"" for original in nodes_text}
```

So, now that we have those stored, we can write a function that converts each node into what we want:

```
def fix_bad_nodes(inputtext):
     # Drop trailing \'s /'s from end of string (3)
     inputtext = re.sub(r"[\/\\]$","",inputtext)
     # Convert all \'s to /'s (2) -- this could be done first?
     inputtext = re.sub(r"\\","\/",inputtext)
     # change the resource group aspect to %
     inputtext = re.sub(r"resource\/group","%",inputtext)
     return inputtext
```

Now that we have a function, we can actually just go back now and populate that dictionary with the modified texts as:

```
replacement_record = {original:fix_bad_nodes(original) for original in nodes_text}
```

Awesome, now we have a dictionary of [original node] --> [fixed], so we can force these changes to the original text as:

```
for original in replacement_record:
     fixed = replacement_record[original]
     doctext = doctext.replace(original,fixed)
```

Cool - now we have a `doctext` object with the substitutions made, and we can export that as,

```
with open(<<path to your file>>,'w') as doc: doc.write(doctext)
```

Cheers :)